# How to limit the number of decimals while logging with Loguru?

Tags: python

I am wondering how I might specify the number of decimal points in some logging output while using `loguru`, consider the following that does not work:

```
from loguru import logger
l1 = [0.123456]
# example from documentation
logger.info("If you're using Python {}, prefer {feature} of course!", 3.6, feature="f-strings")
# my try
logger.info("Eval {0:.3f}".format(l1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `l1` is list and you are treating it as scalar value

Use indexing, it will work

```
from loguru import logger

l1 = [0.123456]
# example from documentation
logger.info("If you're using Python {}, prefer {feature} of course!", 3.6, feature="f-strings")

logger.info("Eval {0:.3f}".format(l1[0]))
```

Output:

```
2021-02-12 06:02:23.680 | INFO     | __main__:<module>:5 - If you're using Python 3.6, prefer f-strings of course!
2021-02-12 06:02:23.682 | INFO     | __main__:<module>:7 - Eval 0.123
```